# Is it possible to change charset encoding in C?

Tags: c, encoding, ascii, iso-8859-2

I would like to make my C program print signs from other charset, not from the ASCII table as it is default. For example, I want to print chars in range [200,250] from the ISO-8859 charset. Is it possible at all? How the compiler should be set?
Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: This question is tagged with `8859-2`.  Is that the `8859` character set you want?  Not `8859-1` also called `latin-1`?

Comment: no, I i would like to display char from different charsets, e.g. 8859-2, WINDOWS-1250 etc.

Answer (score 2):

Setting you locales and using wide characters:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(void) 
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");

    for (wchar_t c = 200; c < 250; c++)
    {
        wprintf(L"%lc", c);
    }
    wprintf(L"\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
ÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øù
```

Comment: how about printing WINDOWS-1250 chars? I use debian btw

Comment: Ah, you are on debian, in this case [iconv](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/iconv_open.3.html) can help

Comment: could u elaborate on that/

Comment: Of course, iconv can convert between different encodings i.e. utf8 to code page 1250 and viceversa.Another option is save your source files (.c) with the desired encoding, c will assume this encoding for your I/O operations

Comment: My locales are es_ES.UTF8

Answer (score 0):

In fact C functions don't care about encoding, so if you have a code like that:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    printf( "Hällo Wörld\n" );
    return( 0 );
}
```

It will print out 'germanzied' "Hello World" in exactly the encoding of the C source file, indepedent from system settings etc. The same is true of course if you print strings that you read from a file. 
If you want to reencode strings (say from UTF-8 to ISO-8859) you have to do t manually or search for an appropriate library

Comment: Well, but i don't want to print a fixed string of chars, i want to print chars from the table of a certain charset